# How to create three views using autolayout, with one fix width height and other two growing height

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to create a view setup vertically where i have one `UIView` (fixed width, height) at the top and two `UILabel`s (fixed width, dynamic height) at the bottom. Padding all around the view (`aView`) is 5. Padding all around of `_mylabel` is 5. Padding on `left` and `right` of `_yourLable` is 5. `_yourLable` will grow as based on text, but when text content is too large, it will just stop to grow for maintain padding from superview of 5.

This is what i have tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *superview = self.view;

    UIView *aView = [UIView new];
    [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [aView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:aView];

    _mylabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [_mylabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [_mylabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [_mylabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    _mylabel.text = @"i am trying to create a view setup vertically where i have one UIView(fix width, height) at top and other two UILables(fix width, dynamic height) at bottom respectively. Padding on allaround of view/lables is 5. this is what i have tried:";
    [self.view addSubview:_mylabel];

    _yourLable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [_yourLable setNumberOfLines:0];
    [_yourLable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [_yourLable setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    _yourLable.text = @"i am trying to create a view setup vertically where i have one UIView(fix width, height) at top and other two UILables(fix width, dynamic height) at bottom respectively. Padding on allaround of view/lables is 5. this is what i have tried:";
    [self.view addSubview:_yourLable];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aView,_mylabel, _yourLable, superview);

    NSArray * heightConstraintforLabel = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[aView(==200)]-5-[_mylabel]-5-[_yourLable]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    NSArray * widthConstraintforView = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[aView]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * widthConstraintformylabel = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[_mylabel]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * widthConstraintforyourLable = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[_yourLable]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    [superview addConstraints:heightConstraintforLabel];
    [superview addConstraints:widthConstraintforView];

    [superview addConstraints:widthConstraintformylabel];

    [superview addConstraints:widthConstraintforyourLable];
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    // Your layout logic here

    CGFloat availableLabelWidth = _mylabel.frame.size.width;
    _mylabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = availableLabelWidth;

    availableLabelWidth = _yourLable.frame.size.width;
    _yourLable.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = availableLabelWidth;
}
```

This is what i am getting, without warnings:

[image: this is what output looks like]

I want both labels to resize based on exact text height.
I want last red label to grow as per text written in it, but never go beyond bottom space of 5. That is it should grow but maintain bottom padding of 5.

I have tried various combination with vertical content compression for labels..., but not got  exact solution.

Help :)

Comment: Breaking constant as I posted in question.

Comment: The exact error - breaking constant is not an error description for autolayout constraints.

Comment: i am adding more info

Comment: Nop cause min target iOS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you have not set the priorities, use

```
[_mylabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:751 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[_mylabel setContentHuggingPriority:252 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

You don't need to set any priorities for `_yourLable`.

And you don't need to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for any of the labels in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, hence you don't need to override `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. You can comment the whole method.

Verified on iOS 7 and iOS 9 devices.

Simulator screenshot looks like this,

[image]